# Silex: Return a new request to another route?

Tags: http, symfony1, request, silex

I'm trying to build a web app using Silex. For some of my routes I'd like the result to be a new request to another route.

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
   //Do something
   //Request route /route2
});

$app->post('/route2', function () use ($app) {
   //Do something else
   return result
});
```

There seems to me that this ought to be a pretty standard use case, but I can't find any simple way to do this. I know about `redirect` but I don't just want to redirect, since I wan't to use a new set of post parameters, created in the first function.

I'm pretty new to both Silex/Symfony and HTTP, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something essential?

Edit: I might add that I've been thinking about modifying the current Request object and replace the post data wih my own parameters and then do a redirect, but there doesn't seem to be any support in the Request class for that.

Comment: I don't think it's a standard use case. You want to generate a request with custom post fields to jump to an other route *without* a redirect... I don't get it :-/

Comment: I'll try to explain a bit better, here's what I want to do:
`1. POST /route1
2. Perform some functions based on post fields
3. POST /route2 with post fields generated in step 2.`

Route1 could for instance run a function to delete an object from a list, when that's done I'd like to call Route2, which will present the updated list. I don't want to present the updated function directly in Route1, since I want to have the possibility to call Route2 from a third route, which could for instance be used to add an object.

Comment: For me, that's basically the goal of a redirect :) Without a redirect here, what will happen if the user refresh the page for the deleted object? It will recall `/route1` to delete the deleted object and then throw an error. If the user add an object, it will be added twice too.

Comment: Yes, that's an issue of course, but the problem with a redirect is that `/route2` will never now what happened at `/route1`, if the operation was successful or not, since `/route2`will only get the original POST data, right?

Comment: Well you have to handle errors on `/route1` since `/route1` will delete the object. If the object can't be deleted, the error will come from `/route1` and then it won't redirect to `/route2`. You can still give other parameters to `/route2` from `/route1`. Like "every thing was ok", "we have one warning", etc ..

Comment: Ok, that sounds exactly like what I'd like to achieve, but I can't figure out how to prepare the redirect with new POST data. In fact, I've been trying around with different HTTP codes in the redirect function, but they are all changed to GET requests anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Request Forwarding](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#forwards) like this:

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
//
$subRequest = Request::create('/route2', 'GET');
return $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
});
```

or instead of `$subRequest`, create your `Request` Object.